# ERROR: The VTYPE function is only valid in the DATA step

Tags: sas

How might one replicate the `vtype` function in `proc fcmp`?

```
proc fcmp;  
  have=1;
  want=vtype(have);
quit;
```

Gives:

> ERROR: The VTYPE function is only valid in the DATA step. User
>   defined libraries will be searched for a definition of this function.

The solution should not involve scanning the variable value.

My attempt at solving this problem is below:

```
proc fcmp;  
  function vtype2 (missval $) $;
    if cats(missval)='.' then return ("N");
    else return("C");
  endsub;
  have=1;
  temp=have;
  call missing(temp);
  want=vtype2(temp);
  file log; put want=;
quit;
```

I had to use `vtype2` to avoid the following:

> ERROR: Built-in SAS FUNCTION or SUBROUTINE already exists with name
>   'vtype'.

Comment: Querying the SASHELP.VCOLUMN data set is probably the best alternative.

Comment: for what?  There is no dataset.

Comment: What are you trying to test? In this program both HAVE and TEMP are defined as numeric given how the program is written. So what is the value of creating the VTYPE2() subroutine? You can hardcode the result for WANT since it does not depend on the anything passed to FCMP.

Comment: HAVE could be either character or numeric, it is necessary to dynamically determine (at runtime) the variable type in order to apply appropriate conditional logic.

Comment: How could HAVE in this program be anything other than a number? Can you create a program where type of HAVE is not known when the code was written?

Comment: Yes, easily.  I did not write the code that is being fed in.  It was written 20 years ago.

Comment: Over 20 years ago before VTYPE() function I used to have a %VARHERE() macro that would generate datastep code to test a variable by name in a running data step. I assume you are looking for something like that for FCMP code, but I am still looking for the use case for it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148236/discussion-between-allan-bowe-and-tom).

Comment: @AllanBowe Stackoverflow chat is blocked by my network security team.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are asking for.  The variable HAVE is something that you have defined in your function. If you want to make another variable that contains something to indicate the type of HAVE in your function you can just hardcode the answer.

Since the VTYPE() function returns 'N' or 'C' for your example you would use.

```
proc fcmp;  
  have=1;
  want='N';
quit;
```

If you have a complex FCMP program where it would be difficult to figure out the variable types and you just want something quick you can add to the end of it then perhaps you can create a macro that will combine the steps in your VTYPE2() function and those you added to generate the data needed for it to work.

```
%macro vtype(varname,result,tempname=_vtype_&sysindex );
&tempname=&varname;
call missing(&tempname);
if cats(&tempname)='.' then &result='N';
else &result='C';
%mend vtype;
```

Here is test program.

```
proc fcmp;  
  have=1;
  %vtype(have,want)
  if want='N' then put 'HAVE is numeric';
  have2='1';
  %vtype(have2,want2)
  if want2='C' then put 'HAVE2 is character';
quit;
```

Comment: I've tried to produce an example of minimal complexity.  The variable "have" is not known at compile time..

Comment: Can you show an example FCMP function where the type of a variable is not known?

Comment: upvoted but there must be a way to add this logic to a `vtype()` function (as per my `vtype2()` attempt)